# How to include Fibonacci levels in Expert Advisor (EA)?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4, mql5, metatrader5

I want to have access to various Fibonacci levels like 23.6%, 38.2%, 50%, 61.8% and 100% in my expert advisor (EA). How can I define those in my EA so that traders can select them via the inputs?

I tried this

```
input double Fibo=23.6;
```

However, is this the common approach? Is it possible to set them as predefined?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set predefined Fibonacci levels by using enumerations. Either you use enumerations provided by MQL5 or define your own, like this:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Enumeration for Fibonacci levels                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
enum ENUM_FIBO_LEVELS
  {
   fib0618 = 0618, // 61.8%
   fib1000 = 1000, // 100.0%
   fib1382 = 1382, // 138.2%
   fib1618 = 1618, // 161.8%
  };
```

Note: If you place a single-line comment, it will be associated with the variable name, as shown in this example.

```
input ENUM_FIBO_LEVELS FiboValue=fib1618; // Fibonacci level
```

As a result, users are able to select their preferred Fibonacci level:

[image: Expert Advisors>Properties>Inputs]

To calculate potential support and resistance levels, convert the Fibonacci `ENUM` level:

```
(double(FiboValue)/1000)
```

If you have any further questions, please leave a comment below.

Comment: Could you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60933737/converting-mql4-ea-to-mql5